# Javascript chained scope and context

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to define a function `run` that acts like this?

```
    a = run('var x = 100;')
    b = run('console.log(x);') // prints 100
    c = run('y = 1;')
    d = run('console.log(y);') // prints 1
```

I tried several ways, using apply and passing the same context, binding a context to a function, returning a closure with a recursive call etc. but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: really bad idea

Comment: Seems like this is masking a more fundamental problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: What has this to do with *scope* and *context* ???

Comment: I want to make a Javascript "interpreter" in a page, in its own separate context and scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, as MyLibrary says, you probably want eval, if you really want to do this.  So:

```
var run = eval;
a = run('var x = 100;')
b = run('console.log(x);') // prints 100
c = run('y = 1;')
d = run('console.log(y);') // prints 1
```

would seem to work.

[JavaScript allows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) assigning functions to variables, so you can set the run variable to eval.  As far as eval, you may want to learn about [it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and as you can see from comments, its use in normal function creation is often discouraged.

Comment: Please don't encourage to use `eval`.

Comment: If I use eval it's going to be run in the window context. I'd like to use my own context and save the changes that eval makes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to eval function?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval